# Tensorflow vs Google Prediction API

Tags: google-api, tensorflow

Talking only about the machine learning libraries (and not about the platform), **is the prediction API available on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) same as its newly released tensorflow library?** Is there any official documentation which clarifies this thing?

Comment: Google is your friend https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs

Comment: This is a valid question and the link provided in the comment about does not help in answering it.